# Transform dpi/dots to pixel gives wrong result

Tags: c#, wpf, printing, resolution, dpi

Currently i to develop a small printer preview, but i have some problem with converting dots per mm / dpi to the pixels on the screen.

For example i have a `Label` which has the coordinations:
top = 5 dots
left = 20 dots

The printer has the resolution of 8 dots per mm / 203 dpi.

In my simple wpf application i have a canvas, where i want to place a label on that place, where it will be printed. So i need to convert the values `20` and `5` relative to my resolution on the screen. But the result in pixels are wrong. That's my calculation:

```
// start values
double top = 5;
double left = 20;

// let's try to calculate the mm. We use 8, because we have 8mm per dot
double mmtop = top / 8.0;
double mmleft = left / 8.0;

// let's turn mm to cm
double cmtop = mmtop * 10.0;
double cmleft = mmleft * 10.0;

// Lets calulate the pixels on the base of a 72dpi monitor
double dpitop = cmtop / 25.4 * 72.0;   // = 318.89
double dpileft = cmleft / 25.4 * 72.0; // = 17.71
```

That's the way i tried to calculate the pixel based position. What am i doing wrong?

Maybe i made some very easy mistake, thank you!

Comment: There are not 25.4 cm in an inch. There are 2.54 cm in an inch, so maybe your `dpitop` and `dpileft` variables have the wrong values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert from mm to cm you need to divide by 10 instead of multiplying by 10.

Comment: Oh, that's very embarrassing. Thank you very much. I will test every thing. That's so, i have no words... :)

Comment: @Sheridan is also correct about the dpi conversion... you'll need to change both to get it working.  Good luck!

Comment: Yep, thank you a lot. Now it seems to work. Sorry for disturbing you, with those mistakes.